# Can't figure out how to clone a repository

Tags: git, clone

I am running Ubuntu 20.04. After a computer disaster, I have rebuilt the system, and now need to fetch a fresh copy of my repository. On github, this looks like dddd/PPPP.
After changing the directory to ~/AA/BB (where my project root should be) I have loaded git. git init gives me "Reinitialized existing git repository in /home/me/AA/BB"
How do I now clone my repository? I can't seem to get the syntax right. I tried:
`git clone dddd@github.com:PPPP`

```
Cloning into ''PPPP'
dddd@github.com:Permission denied (publickey)
fatal: could not read from remote repository
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when I factory reset my computer and was trying to clone a **private repository**. For me, what worked was to [create a new SSH key pair](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) and add the public key to my Github account. Please see this [website](https://careerkarma.com/blog/git-permission-denied-publickey/#:%7E:text=Conclusion-,The%20%E2%80%9CPermission%20denied%20(publickey).,add%20your%20key%20to%20Git.).

Answer (score 1):

Given that you've probably created a new ssh key-pair, you probably do need to update things over on GitHub, as [Rafael García said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67844844/1256452).  Follow the listed instructions there.  But there's something else important here:

> [Running] `git init` gives me `Reinitialized existing git repository in /home/me/AA/BB`

This means you *already have a clone*—or at least, a *repository*.  You probably don't need a new clone.

Remember, `git clone` means:

- make a new, empty repository (`git init` in a new, empty directory);
- in the new empty repository, add a *remote:* a name like `origin`—the default name *is* `origin` but you can pick a different one (don't)—that holds a URL so that you don't have to keep retyping the URL;
- run `git fetch` against this remote, to get all the *commits* from some other existing Git repository: whoever answers the Internet-phone-call at the URL is expected to speak Git protocol, and the URL thus refers to *their* repository, which has commits and *their* branches;
- once you have all their *commits*, create *remote-tracking names* from their *branch* names: this way you have all of their commits but *none of their branches;* and finally
- create one local branch, using the same commit hash ID as in one of *their* branches, so that you have one branch name—such as `master` or `main`—that matches your `origin/master` or `origin/main`, that your Git made based on their `master` or `main`.

So we use `git clone` to *copy a repository*.  The result is a new repository in which we have *our own* branches.  We don't get *their* branches: we take their branch names and turn those into our *remote-tracking names*, like `origin/main` or whatever.  From this point on, we have *our* repository to work in.  We only need to call up *their* Git, at the saved URL, to *get new commits from them* (and update our remote-tracking names) or to *give new commits to them* (with `git push`, which ends by asking them to set one of their *branch* names).

After you've updated your ssh key information over on GitHub—which you can test with `ssh -Tv git@github.com` to see if GitHub recognizes you correctly now—you will almost certainly want to run `git fetch`, not `git clone`, so as to *update your existing clone* by getting any new commits they have, that you don't.  Using `git fetch` has your Git call up their Git, using the stored URL.  You can run `git fetch origin` to be explicit that the name of the remote is `origin`, but unless you have more than one *remote*, the name will always be `origin` (well, unless you did what I said "don't do" above ).  Git will then figure it out on its own.

Note that `git pull` is a convenience command.  It means: *first, run `git fetch`, then, when that's finished, run a second Git command to incorporate any new commits we just got into my current branch*.  That *second* Git command messes with *your* branches.  The first one just downloads their commits, and is therefore safe to run at any time.  The *second* Git command requires being in a proper, ready-to-go state (you can check with `git status`).

I personally prefer to run `git fetch` (whenever), and then at my own chosen time, run my own chosen second command, rather than just blindly running `git pull`.  This really is a personal preference thing though: if you prefer to run the two commands back-to-back, without being able to see what you'll be merging or rebasing first, you can use `git pull`.  Lots of people prefer that.  It's fine to *do* it: you just need to *know what it means*, because when things go wrong, you need to know *which second command you chose* and how to fix things up at that point.  (The fetch step almost never fails—it mostly only breaks if your Internet connection is down—and if it's that step that fails, Git doesn't run the second command at all.  So in general, all the failures are from the second command.)

Answer (score 0):

I think I correctly generated a new SSH pair - {ssh -Tv git@github.com }
generated a ton of output that seemed to be happy.
Then I tried to fetch and this happened: {me@Dell:~/Portal/Portal$ sudo git fetch dddd@github.com:PPPP
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.112.4' to the list of known hosts.
dddd@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
d}
Any ideas?

Comment: what is the output of the command "git remote -v". I wonder if you have a remote set up on your system.

Comment: git remote -v returned nothing.

Comment: So then I did: git remote add ..... and I now have the same url for fetch and push

Comment: origin https://github.com/dms489/Portal (fetch)origin htpps

Comment: Sorry, can't figure how to put a new line in a comment

Comment: Now, git fetch origin asks for user name (dms489?) and password,

Comment: I know the password I used is correct, but it kicks me out (sigh!)

Comment: Should the user name be my full e-mail address?

Comment: Just realized the bloody thing is asking for the password to https://dms489@github.com (sigh!)

Comment: Sounds like you're good now, Right?    p.s. you can't put a newline in comments. It's deliberate, so that comments are kept simple :)

Comment: I waded through all the output from 'ssh -Tv git@github.com' and found this: 'you've successfully authenticated but Github does not supply shell access.' 'ssh -Tv github.com' died. Do I need to put git@ somewhere?

Comment: Well, no I'm not OK. It doesn't want the password here that I use to log in to github and Ubuntu